# (Re)Initializing object without copy constructor in cpp

Tags: c++, stack

This question is targeted to embedded systems!

I have the following options to initialize an object:

```
Object* o = new Object(arg);
```

This puts the object in the heap and returns a pointer to it. I prefer not to use dynamic allocation in embedded software.

```
Object o = Object(arg);
```

This creates a new object in the stack and then copies it to object `o` and removes it after. This can cause stack overflow if the object is big enough to fit in RAM but not in the stack. I have seen this happening with optimization turned off, I haven't explored if it's different with optimization enabled.

```
Object o(arg);
```

This creates the object without making a copy, however how can I "initialize" `o` again?

For embedded I prefer the last option since the heap is not used and there's no temporary object in the stack that can do a stack overflow.

However I am puzzled on how I can reinitialize the object again since:

```
o.Object(arg)
```

is not allowed.

I could create a method called init(arg) and call

```
o.init(arg)
```

that does the same initialization as `Object::Object(arg)` but I would prefer not to have to create an extra method with a "non-standard" name I need to remember.

Is there a way to call the constructor of an already created object to reinitialize it again without making a copy?

Comment: *"This creates a new object in the stack and then copies it to object o and removes it after."* - Only if your compiler is well and truly utterly daft.... Ah, I see you compiled without optimizations...

Comment: Does your class support *move* semantics or does it have a `swap(...)` function?

Comment: If you define the object as `Object o;` then just *assign* to it to "initialize" it again? As in `o = Object();`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to "initialize" it again?

Comment: @StoryTeller Since I'm programming for embedded I prefer to have control over the memory and I place all the variables of "big" things outside any function so they are allocated on compile time and I know they fit. I like to initialize them in a init function since the code is a bit more tidy in my opinion. In some cases also it may be needed to reinitialize an object if I put the processor to sleep and some hardware requires re initialization as well as the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using placement new on your object's current memory. This will initialize a new object in currently used memory without allocating new memory. That might be a solution for you. For example:

```
new (&o) Object(args)
```

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    A(int i)
    {
        m_i = i;
    }

    int m_i;
};

int main()
{
    int s = 10;
    int *ps = new (&s) int(100);
    std::cout << *ps;
    std::cout << s;

    A a(5);
    new (&a) A(49);
    std::cout << a.m_i;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++98 main.cpp` returns 10010049, which is correct.

Comment: error:  #384: no instance of overloaded "operator new"  matches the argument list

In which version of C++ was this added?

Comment: Some info on placement new can be found here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/
It's quite old . I think C++-98 should already have it.
Also stack overflow question on placement new:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: note that this does not automatically call the destructor on the first instance of `A`

Answer (score 3):

You need use placement new and call the object destructor example below

```
A a = A();//init
a.~A();//clear
new (&a) A();//re init
```

Comment: That code is UB, you can only explcitly delete if you have used placement new in the first place.

Comment: @john No it's not, where did you ever see that?

Comment: Note that this approach might require to catch exceptions if they can by thrown by the constructor of `A`. Otherwise, the destructor would be invoked for an object that has not been constructed, which is UB.

Comment: @DanielLangr im going to assume for this example that A() will construct the class successfully

Comment: @DanielLangr - Considering the OP emphasizes "embedded" several times, I doubt exceptions are likely.

Comment: @john I don't see any such requrement: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#12.sentence-6, at least in the section about destructors.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Get a compiler that works (that is recognizes most obvious opportunities to intialize object in place) and supports at least C++11.

Step 2. For initialization use:

```
auto o = Object(arg); // won't copy ever with optimization turned on
```

If you need to reassign with new arguments to the constructor:

```
o = Object(arg1); // calls move asignment operator
```

If you need to overwrite the value with value of different object (which you don't plan on using afterwards:

```
o = std::move(o1); // o1 is the other Object, afterwards o1 is left in 'valid but undefinded state'
```

If that doesn't work for you (still stack thrashing / no move assignment operator, etc.), you should probably go for placement new, explicitly calling the destructor like @tomer zeitune suggests:

```
o.~Object(); // cleanup
new (&o) Object();
```

Explicit call to destructor is required to e.g. release all the resources managed by the object.

Comment: We do not know if arbitrary "Object" provided without definition has any move assignment operators or not.

Comment: The compiler still places the object in the stack to move it later when I turn on optimizations to level O3. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to use `o = Object(arg1);`